# Nodejs/Express unable to consistently retrieve body from post. Multiple calls in quick succession succeed

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating a simple Mock server that I want to (for now) respond to a post with the body of the request.  I am experiencing an issue where I am unable to consistently retrieve the body of that request.

It does work sometimes, but only if I make multiple posts quickly.  If I delay more than 5 seconds between posts, the body appears to be {}.

How can I ensure that I always retrieve the body?  I appreciate any help provided!  I am new to node, so I am sure there are some obvious errors.

1. I am sending the request using Postman, and have set a header for "Content-Type" with value "application/json".
2. I am using bodyParser.json() after defining app, but before using routes.

Joining middleware and listening:

```js
app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var router = require('./router.js');
app.use(router);

httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(webServerConfig.port)
.on('listening', () => {
console.log(`Web server listening on localhost:${webServerConfig.port}`);
```

Relevant portion of router:

```
router.route('/api/v1/customer')
  .post(customers.post);
```

Post function called by the router:

```
function post(req, res, next) {
  try {
    var body = req.body;
    console.log('post: ', body);
    res.status(200).json(req.body);
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500);
    next(err);
  }
}
```

Body of first response (or having waiting 5 seconds between responses):

```
{}
```

Body of subsequent responses, when made in quick succession (this is also the body that I send in the post request):

```
{
    "phone": "8124713403",
    "smsOptStatus": "out",
    "addressLine1": "100 Regolith Lane",
    "birthDay": 2,
    "firstName": "Bill",
    "emailAddress": "test3sldkfjslkdfa@live.com",
    "lastName": "Shepherd",
    "emailOptStatus": "in",
    "city": "Mooncity",
    "loyaltyStatus": "member",
    "birthMonth": 7,
    "state": "CA"
}
```

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with your code, possibly something is with your client-side code, would you please post them too?

Comment: Just a couple of notes, you don't have to call `next` after you called `res.send`.
Also, you can call it short `res.json(req.body)`, you do not need to specify the 200 status

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer I am using the standalone Postman client to post the request.  The 'Body' of the request is identical to the response I receive (when it works).  I have chosen 'raw' and 'JSON (application/json)' as the type.  I have confirmed that the header contains the Key 'Content-Type' and the value 'application/json'.  I've attempted to reproduce the issue using curl, but always receive the {}.

Comment: Ok, So I tried to run your code on my machine, and it works all the times.
Probably something is wrong with other parts of your code

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer Thanks for your help!  I can at least rule this part of it out, which is super helpful.  Thanks again!